# flush without sync

Tags: c, file, operating-system

From what I've read, flush pushes data into the OS buffers and sync makes sure that data goes down to the storage media. So, if you want to be sure that data is actually written to disk, you need to do a flush followed by a sync. So, are there any cases where you want to call flush but not sync?

Comment: when you want to be able to free the buffer?

Comment: A little suggestion: Instead of calling `flush` every time, you can use the `write` system call, which does unbuffered writes (directly to OS buffers). This would only require you to call `sync`, if necessary

Answer (score 3):

You only want to [`fflush`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) if you're using stdio's `FILE *`. This writes a user space buffer to the kernel.

The other answers seem to be missing [`fdatasync`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fdatasync). This is the system call you want to flush a specific file descriptor to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lots.  Most programs most of the time would not bother to call any of the various sync operations; flushing the data into the kernel buffer pool as you close the file is sufficient.  This is doubly true if you're using a journalled file system.

Note that flushing is a higher level operation than the `read()` or similar system calls.  It is used by the C `<stdio.h>` library, or the C++ `<iostream>` library.  The system calls inherently flush the data to the kernel buffer pool (or direct to disk if you're using direct I/O or something similar).

Note, too, that on POSIX-like systems, you can arrange for data sync etc by setting flags on the [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) system call (`O_SYNC`, `O_DSYNC`, `O_RSYNC`), or subsequently via `fcntl()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you `fflush`, you flush the buffer of one file to disk (unless you give NULL, in which case it flushes all open files). http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fflush/

When you `sync`, you flush all the buffers to disk. http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/sync/

The most important thing that you should notice is that `fflush` is a standard function, while `sync` is a system call provided by the operating system (Linux for example).

So basically, if you are writing portable program, you in fact never use `sync`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, `fflush()` applies only when using the `FILE` interface of UNIX that buffers writes at the application level. In case the normal `write()` call is used, `fflush()` makes little sense.

Having said that, I can think of two situations where you would like to call `fflush()` but not sync:

1. You want to make sure that the data will eventually make it to disk even though the application crashes.
2. Force to screen the data that the application has written to standard output so far.

The second case is the most common use I have seen and it is usually required if the `printf()` call does not end with a new line character ('\n').